# Improving performance of React-native app

Tags: react-native

I'm currently using https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer to resize a bunch of pictures, the problem is that it is quite slow, and one solution that came to mind would be to do the resizing in parallel - if possible.

As the package currently does return a Promise, I assume it **might** be possible to simple parallelize it, but I haven't found info on this and I don't know how to actually check if it is spawning multiple threads (but I assume it is not doing that)

Either way, are promise calls truly parallel when they involve native code? and if not, what can be done to properly use all cores on a mobile device?

Comment: You could try using a `Promise.all` and see if that improves the resizing.

Comment: Javascript is still mostly single threaded, so you won't get concurrent execution in the JS code, which is what it seems you're asking.  However, with promises you get asynchronous processing (native can do whatever it does), so if you pack all your image resize requests into an array and run it through Promise.all, they will resolve/reject in an indeterminate order, but overall will resolve if each one resolves, or reject if any single one rejects.  Promise.all could potentially boost performance for you.

Comment: I'm currently using `Promise.all` - the question is if it is going to be truly parallel, or not when it calls native code (it's not bad practice to use Promise.all anyway!)

Comment: I'm sure you could look in the repo at the native code to see what it's doing.